# JqueryMobile radiobutton horizontal group does not render properly

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I'm trying to programmatically create a group of radio-buttons in JqueryMobile. Everything works fine except for the `data-type='horizontal'` property:

as you can see in **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/E42C8/6/)** fiddle, the "created-via-js" radio group does not render properly, while the other one (written directly into the HTML) works great.

I'm following the **Horizontal Group** example that you can find on **[this](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/widgets/radiobuttons/#&ui-state=dialog)** page

This is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JS**

```
for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    var rowList1 = '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">' +
        '<legend>This does not render properly..</legend>' +
        '<input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="on" checked="checked" type="radio">' +
        '<label for="radio-choice-h-2a">One</label>' +
        '<input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="off" type="radio">' +
        '<label for="radio-choice-h-2b">Two</label>' +
        '<input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2c" value="other" type="radio">' +
        '<label for="radio-choice-h-2c">Three</label>' +
        '</fieldset>';
    $("#container").append(rowList1);
}
$("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio().checkboxradio("refresh");
```

What am I doing wrong? Any idea?

Thanks in advance, best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try triggering the `create` method on the parent container and not directly on the inputs, for example

```
$('#container').trigger('create');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E42C8/7/)